# Как на php вывести один элемент из массива полученого из mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Собственно есть массив, print_r віводит его так:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [1_nom] => 9-13-20-72 ) )
```

Надо передать в переменную это значение '9-13-20-72', но никак не получается, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас скорее всего где-то ошибка, потому что ни переменная, ни название свойства объекта не могут начинаться с цифры. А так получить нужное значение вы можете с помощью:

```php
// Где "property" — название свойства, в вашем случае это "1_nom"
$variable = $data[0]->property;
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, 1_nom - было название столбца базы, переименовал в nom_1 и все заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @Leon, в принципе не обязательно переименовывать столбец, вы можете в sql-запросе указать для него псевдоним: `SELECT 1_nom AS column FROM table;`.